# How to run Diablo 2 in VirtualBox on big screens?

Tags: diablo-ii

When you run it in windowed mode it is tiny.

And when you run it in fullscreen mode, it crashes.

**How can I run it at proper resolution without crashing?**

Answer (score 3):

1. Make virtualbox windowed.
2. Turn off "Auto-resize guest display" in the View menu.
3. Resize your window to 4:3 and as big as possible.
4. Turn on "Auto-resize guest display" in the View menu.
5. Modify the shortcut to diablo.exe or (to PlugY.exe) to include these parameters: "-w -nofixaspect"
6. Start the game using this shortcut
7. Maximize the window
8. Do not forget to set 800x600 in the game menu.

Not perfect, but still much better than native resolution:

[image: Diablo 2 running in multiple windows]

Comment: I'd suggest to install [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html). These will enable proper screen resolutions and other things making your life much easier.

Comment: They are installed, but the game crashes in fullscreen mode.